# GCloud API for GKE Services & Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Is there a way to query from an API the resources under `Kubernetes Engine > Services & Ingress` in the GCloud console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question. The answer is slightly complicated.

Essentially, IIUC, you want to list the Kubernetes services and ingresses for your cluster(s). This functionality is provided by Kubernetes' API server rather than Kubernetes Engine itself.

So, you can do this various ways but, commonly (using the [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) command-line):

```sh
kubectl get services [--namespace=${NAMESPACE}]
kubectl get ingresses [--namespace=${NAMESPACE}]
```

If you've deployed e.g. Kubernetes [Web UI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) formerly Dashboard, you should be able to enumerate the services|ingresses through it too.

You may also interact directly with your clusters' API servers to make the underlying REST API call that's made by `kubectl` using the above commands.

For Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Console is accessing 2, distinct APIs:

1. The Kubernetes Engine API that provisions|manages clusters and is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/), accessible through Console and `gcloud`.
2. The Kubernetes API that provisions|manages resources (e.g. Pods, Deployments, Services, Ingress etc.) that are owned by the cluster and are documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/), some (!) are accessible through Console. All are accessible directly or commonly using Kubernetes' command-line `kubectl`.